# Call a procedure in Scheme after waiting a few seconds?

Tags: scheme, lisp

Is it possible to call a procedure in Scheme after waiting a few seconds?

For example:

```
(define (facs)
(fac 3)
;wait 5 seconds
(fac 7))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no provision for a sleep procedure in Standard Scheme; you will need to rely on implementation-specific features.

If you are using Guile Scheme, you can use `sleep` to sleep for a number of seconds, or `usleep` to sleep for a number of microseconds:

```
(define (delayed-5s msg)
  (display "Waiting 5s...")
  (force-output)
  (sleep 5)
  (newline)
  (display msg)
  (newline))
```

Note that you should flush the output to be sure that messages are seen when you want them seen. Typically, (but not always) printing a newline will flush the output buffer, so you could move `(newline)` before `(sleep 5)` and reasonably expect that the display will work as expected; but it is better to flush the output explicitly to ensure that messages are flushed from the output buffer when you want them to be. In the above code, both `force-output` and `sleep` are Guile-specific procedures.

If you are using Chez Scheme, you can do this:

```
(define (delayed-5s msg)
  (display "Waiting 5s...")
  (flush-output-port (current-output-port))
  (sleep (make-time 'time-duration 0 5))
  (newline)
  (display msg)
  (newline))
```

In Chez Scheme, `sleep` takes a *time* object, and `make-time` takes three arguments, returning a *time* object. The first of those is a *time-type* argument, the second is the number of nanoseconds, and the third is the number of seconds. Again, you should flush the output buffer, and `flush-output-port` does that, but it needs an *output-port*, which the procedure `current-output-port` provides. In the above code, `sleep` and `make-time` are Chez-specific procedures, but `flush-output-port` and `current-output-port` are standard R6RS Scheme library procedures.

You can see that using the sleep facility provided by Chez Scheme is a little bit more involved than the one provided by Guile Scheme. Other implementations are likely to have similar provisions, but they are not required to.

Answer (score 1):

Not in portable Scheme as far as I know.  Many implementations will have ways of doing this, of course.  For instance in Racket:

```
(define (sleepy s)
  (values (current-seconds)
          (begin
            (sleep s)
            (current-seconds))))
```

```
> (sleepy 2)
1612809817
1612809819
```

(Of course, `current-seconds` is *also* not part of standard Scheme.)